# Swift 3 - Rest Api HTTP Header Values are not being sent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rest, swift3

I'm trying to build an app with Swift, which makes a REST API call with an authorization header. The code looks like this:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("username:password", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("de", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Language")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
     ...
     ...
```

My problem is that the HTTP Header values are somehow not being sent. I verified that the requests values are being set by printing out `request.allHTTPHeaderFields`, but the response from the server still holds all the default values for the headers. This is not only for the `Authorization` header but also for any other header I try to change.

It would be great if someone can find the mistake... I mean, it is a very simple piece of code, so I'm really confused to where it went wrong.

Comment: What is the response code? Does the request require Basic Authentication? If so, the Authorization header is not correct - value should be `Basic <base64-encoded username:password>`. Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: The response code WAS 401, so unauthorized. But i set the authorization value to `<base64-encoded username:password>`, without the prepended `Basic`. I now tried your solution and it gave me 403 (so Forbidden) as the response code. That basically means I don't have the right to access the API with my credentials, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is likely the credentials do not have access rights to the resource.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!